# How to programatically post to instagram

Tags: python, automation, instagram, instagram-api

ok, I'm really confused...

There seems to be a fair few posts on this, but are all outdated as I have tried about 15 different python bots and code sections and cant get them to work.

*It seems that the API's have changed in the past year and thus every developer who had a working bot is now left unable to.*

I'm confused at to why, as there are services like Later .com and others that allow people to post to their instagram account. So there has to be a programmable way to do this.

I had a look at the API docs for their API but I can only seen to find 2 and none of them allow posting to your profile:

1. Instagram Graph API

> The API can be used to get their media, manage and reply to comments on their media, identify media where they have been @mentioned by other Instagram users, find hashtagged media, and get basic metadata and metrics about other Instagram Businesses and Creators.

This only says get their media, not publish.

2. Instagram Basic Display API

> The API can be used to access any type of Instagram account but only provides read-access to basic data. If you are building an app that will allow Instagram Businesses or Creators to publish media, moderate comments, identify @mentioned and hashtagged media, or get data about other Instagram users, use the Instagram Graph API instead.

This one says should I want to publish media then I should go to the Instagram Graph API, again which doesnt say I can publish.

Let's say for the sake of this convo that the one I should use is the Instagram Graph API. The requirements for this are:

> Before you can switch your app to Live Mode you must complete the App Review process. You can begin the process in the App Review > Permissions and Features tab within the App Dashboard. All Instagram Graph API permissions except for pages_show_list require App Review approval.

> Once you complete App Review you will be asked to complete Business Verification. You must complete verification before your app will be able to use Advanced Access Levels.

All I want to do is automate the posting of my personal instagram account so I can bulk edit photos and do all that in one day without having to create a full working live app that people can use or a business.

Please, for the love of all that is automation, please point me in the right direction to do this..

Answer (score 0):

The instagram API does not support uploading images.

I too was frustrated with how much effort one has to invest to discover this.  After all, posting an image seems like a fundamental use case for an API.  I wish there was a FAQ page, or bold disclaimer that makes it clear.

There are projects on github that support posting to Instagram in unsupported ways (e.g. using a "private" api, or simulating the Instagram app).  I haven't personally used any of these solutions, but wanted to mention they exist.

Answer (score 0):

With the new Facebook Graph API, you *can* make an Instagram post. But this API, hence the post functionality, works only with the Instagram Businesses and Creators users.
In your case, just switch to the Creators account.